# How to align a line over three or more buttons in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, alignment

I am creating a Tic Tac Toe game in which I want to show a small animation after the game is over to show how a player won, somewhat like this:

[image: Test animation]

So there should be a animation which shows how a player won. I am having trouble on how to make this work. I've tried using a ImageView / Line but I have no idea on how to make it align perfectly from the edge of a button on a row to the end of the row and there is also a special case if there is a diagonal win. If I somehow get a line to show up I'm sure adding a animation to it won't be much difficult. Although I'm confused where to even start on this!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Note**: I know how to align a line somewhere on the scene, I'm having trouble on aligning it from the start to end of the edges of three or more particular nodes.

Comment: The answer to this is highly dependent on your code.  We don’t know if you’re using a Canvas to draw the grid, X’s, and O’s yourself, or using a layout.

Comment: @VGR Well there are buttons as I said in the question, they simply just have the text(X's and O's) written onto it. As for how I'm adding it to a scene, there is a Grid Pane which has 3 buttons on each row/column. (3 x 3)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out;
So basically what you'll do it get the layoutX/Y of that particular node and set that layoutX/Y to be the startX/Y of the line and the end of the line would be the layoutX/Y of the node at the end of the row/column.
I've attached some code if you need more help:

```
    Button button1 = new ButtonBuilder("1").setSize(50, 50).build();
    Button button2 = new ButtonBuilder("2").setSize(50, 50).build();
    Button button3 = new ButtonBuilder("3").setSize(50, 50).build();

    HBox hBox = new HBox(20);
    hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    hBox.getChildren().addAll(button1, button2, button3);

    Line line = new Line();
    line.setStroke(Color.RED);
    line.setStrokeWidth(20);

    root.getChildren().addAll(hBox, line);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    System.out.println(hBox.getChildren().get(0).getLayoutX() + "\n" +
            hBox.getChildren().get(0).getLayoutY() + "\n" +
            hBox.getChildren().get(2).getLayoutX() + "\n" +
            hBox.getChildren().get(2).getLayoutY());

    System.out.println("Setting line co-ords: ");
    line.setStartX(hBox.getChildren().get(0).getLayoutX());
    line.setStartY(hBox.getChildren().get(0).getLayoutY());
    line.setEndX(hBox.getChildren().get(2).getLayoutX());
    line.setEndY(hBox.getChildren().get(2).getLayoutY());
```

Keep in mind you can only get the co-ords of the nodes **after** you show your stage.
And then you'll animate the nodes as you do normally. TADA!